# What is the proportion of primes that can be written as $a^2 + b^2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

We know that a prime $p$ can be written as a sum of squares if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Do we have any idea what proportion of primes are of the form $4k + 1$ for some $k$?

I suppose it would require more knowledge about prime numbers, though I'm not sure what work has been done on this.

Comment: It is $50$-$50$. If $N_1(x)$ is the number of primes of the form $4k+1$ that are $\le x$, and $N_3(x)$ is the same for $4k+3$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{N_1(x)}{N_3(x)}=1$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions#Distribution

Comment: It is not an easy theorem to prove. I think the result (for more general arithmetic sequences) was first proved by de la Vallee-Poussin, not many years after he and Hadamard had proved the Prime Number Theorem.  The behaviour of $N_1(x)$ and $N_3(x)$ is quite interesting. You might enjoy the paper *Prime Number Races*, which should not be hard to track down.

Comment: See Ingham, The Distribution of Prime Numbers, pp. 106-107.

Answer (score 3):

A very nice paper talking about all this stuff is  [Prime Number Races](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/PrimeRace.pdf) .
You will find it interesting!